# What is .NET Equivalent of InterruptedException (Java)?

Tags: c#, .net

I am converting Java program into C#.

I am wondering what is the .NET equivalent of Java's **InterruptedException**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is [`ThreadInterruptedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadinterruptedexception.aspx).